# Почему не обновляется defaultValue?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook

Не обновляется `defaultValue` у input.

Как можно обновить значение по умолчанию?

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const DifficultyComponent = () => {

    const DifficultyGetServer = () => {
        fetch('/getDifficulty').then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                setDifficulty(data['difficulty'])
            }
        );
    }

    const [maxNumber, setMaxNumber] = useState(5);
    const [difficulty, setDifficulty] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        DifficultyGetServer();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="form-group">
            <label htmlFor="difficulty">Сложность игры (Максимальное число: {maxNumber})</label>
            <input type="number" className="form-control" id="difficulty" min="1" defaultValue={difficulty} onChange={(e) => setMaxNumber(e.target.value * 5)}/>
        </div>
    );
};

export default DifficultyComponent;
```

Comment: `defaultValue` у `input`-а? Для начального значения можно и просто использовать `value` и положить туда начальное значение

Comment: @EzioMercer сделал. А как можно чекбокс? что бы галочка была установлена по умолчанию
 <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="plus" defaultChecked={operators['plus']} onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)} />
defaultChecked не хочет, хоть true и стоит

Comment: Откуда вы берёте приставку `default`? Пишите просто `checked`

Comment: а, оу. спасибо...